# cabal: cannot configure random-1.0.1.3. It requires base >=5 && <5

Tags: haskell, centos, ghc, cabal, pandoc

I am trying to install `pandoc` on CentOS 6.5.

```
$ ghc -V; cabal -V
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.2
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

I run:

```
cabal update
cabal install pandoc
```

and I get:

```
cabal: cannot configure random-1.0.1.3. It requires base >=5 && <5
There is no available version of base that satisfies >=5 && <5
```

I can't find a way around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a newer version of cabal-install, the one you're using is rather old and has a rather weak dependency solver.

Comment: when I do `cabal update cabal-install` I get: `cabal: cannot configure random-1.0.1.3. It requires base >=5 && <5
There is no available version of base that satisfies >=5 && <5`

Comment: ok, I think I have this, downloaded a new cabal-install and ran bootstrap.sh and its working away. Fingers crossed.